# reStructuredText Multilevel

Tags: restructuredtext, multi-level

How can I get such a structur with reStructuredText? Is it even possible?

```
1. Title
    1.1 Subtitle
         1.1.2 SubSubtitle
             1.1.2.1 SubSubtitle
    1.2 2ndSubtitle
         1.2.1 2ndSubSubtitle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer here:

```
Title
=====
   Subtitle
   --------
     ___________
     SubSubtitle
     ___________

        SubSubSubtitle 1
        ________________

        SubSubSubtitle 2
        ________________  

     _____________
     SubSubtitle 2
     _____________         

Title 2
=======
```

The Output would be (if numbered doctree):

```
1. Title
   1.1 Subtitle
       1.1.1 SubSubtitle
             1.1.1.1 SubSubSubtitle 1
             1.1.1.2 SubSubSubtitle 2
       1.1.2 SubSubtitle 2
2. Title 2
```

For more information check out: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickstart.html#sections

Comment: This example will not work. Section markup cannot be indented in reStructuredText (except for the title in an under- *and* overlined section heading.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the [Sphinx documentation for nested lists](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#lists-and-quote-like-blocks)? Your question should show that you made *some* effort, including what documentation you read, what you tried, what you expected, and what you observed.

> Nested lists are possible, but be aware that they must be separated from the parent list items by blank lines:

```
* this is
* a list

  * with a nested list
  * and some subitems

* and here the parent list continues
```

Substitute `#.` for `*`.

Answer (score 0):

The **structure** can be achieved with a nested enumerated list:

```
#. Title

    #. Subtitle
    
         #. SubSubtitle
         
             #. SubSubtitle
             
    #. 2ndSubtitle
    
         #. 2ndSubSubtitle
```

The desired numbering would require a set of custom CSS rules.
Docutils supports some numbering styles (cf.
https://docutils.sourceforge.io/test/functional/expected/standalone_rst_html5.html#enumerated-lists) but not this one.