# Inconsistent line spacing in RestructuredText document

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm build RST files for my company's documentation.  One irritating thing is that enumerated lists don't seem to have any consistency in terms of line spacing.

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Robert

Comment: Please provide example rST markup. There is a right way to do it, but the white space rules are tricky. Possible answers for nested enumerated lists https://stackoverflow.com/a/44913122/2214933 https://stackoverflow.com/a/44559466/2214933

Answer (score 2):

It's a well known problem of `docutils`, the library on which Sphinx is built.

From Sphinx issue tracker on GitHub:

> **[tk0miya](https://github.com/tk0miya) wrote:**
>   In my short investigation:
>
> The behavior comes from `docutils` (base library of Sphinx).
>   In `docutils.writers.html4css1.HTMLTranslator`, `docutils` generates `<p>` tag if list includes any items excepting paragraphs and nested lists.
>
> To fix this, set `self.compact_simple` in `visit_list_item` instead of `visit_bullet_list` and `visit_enumerated_list`.
>   But we have to know why docutils check whole of list.
>
> Source: [Spinx-Doc/Sphinx #2258 - Nested field lists inside list items cause unwanted space in HTML output](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2258)

---

See related issues:

- https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/119

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure how to apply Paebbels answer, however I was able to get rid of the `<p>` tags by changing to the html4 writer by adding this line to my `conf.py`.

`html4_writer = true`

This obviously changes it to the html4 writer, so you'll need to determine whether this is acceptable or not.